# How to show last Date of when the last time Data was loaded into an specific Table - plsql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, plsqldeveloper

I hope somebody can help because I can not find an solution with google.
I am using plsql developer.

Which select statement can show me for an specific table, at which date the last time an row has bin inserted.

For Example Table: 'dogs' 
data inserted on the 12. Februar.
Today is the 14. Februar

I need an SQL that shows me the 12 of Februar.
Is their any sys - table which logs this? If yes i can't find it.

Can anybody help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this query to your table

```
 select scn_to_timestamp(max(ora_rowscn)) from table;
```